# Xamarin Android: FreshChat SDK Implementation in xamarin forms giving exception

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have downloaded Android SDK 5.1.0 from url https://github.com/freshworks/freshchat-android/releases

of SDK Documentation:
https://support.freshchat.com/en/support/solutions/articles/50000000207-freshchat-android-sdk-integration-steps#4.1-Conversations

to implement it in xamarin.android project and this sdk is using handlers for click and some other events.

I converted this jar file into .dll using Xamarin Android Class Library. (jar build action is InputJar).
When I rebuild this class library project then no errors came and it released .dll successfully

Then I referenced this dll into my project and I rebuild it.
Here, I got some handler related issues that these handlers are not registered/missing in activity.

(1) error: package com.freshchat.consumer.sdk does not exist
com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.FreshchatWebViewListener

(2) error: package com.freshchat.consumer.sdk does not exist
com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.FreshchatUserInteractionListener

(3) error: package com.freshchat.consumer.sdk does not exist
com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.FreshchatActionListener

[This is Android Class Library where I added sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PhOo.png)

[Here, I referenced ClassLibrary .dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mG6d.png)

[handlers from sdk is appeared as a interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcgds.png)

[MainActivity.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUYRl.png)

[Errors when I rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKKbf.png)

When I click on one of these error then it shows some definition in referenced sdk:
[com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.FreshchatWebViewListener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvi0q.png)

Codewise I have not consumed sdk function in the mainactivity.

It looks like sdk is using some handlers which need to define in the MainActivity.cs

Am I defining in a wrong way or path is wrong for this sdk implementation.

Please suggest how to fix these errors while class library implementation.

Comment: You need to provide enough details that someone can figure out why you are getting these errors. Show whatever xml or code you have related to "converting this jar file into .dll". Show where these packages are referenced. Have you googled the error message? Is there a website or github for this jar file? Look there. Also, why do you say this is a "handler binding issue"? Those error messages have nothing to do with "handlers".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Details has been provided.

Comment: Could you integrate freshChat in Xamarin?  I am trying to integrate it in Xamarin Forms but, I'm getting same errors :(

Comment: @JohanEcAv Unfortunately I am not able to integrate. Its giving some exception on 
FreshChatConfigOption config=new FreshChatConfigOption(some params);
FreshChat.Instance.Init(config); //here

Comment: What error do you get? I got : Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 'Failed resolution of: Lcom/freshchat/consumer/sdk/R$string;'

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: FreshChat library: they have included 1 sample. so you need to go to sample/...android res folder/
all values need to copy to xamarin android resource folder like layout, values everything.
then try to compile and fix issues.

Comment: freshchat.jar using res folder as a dependency for binding lib you have created. 
also add nuget v4, v7 support, android x all